# How to send command to Dell 2850 gen II?

Tags: dell, drac, dell-openmanage

Sorry for a dumb question, but..
I need to reset DRAC password on this server.
I've read (http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19316985) that I have to install OMSA in order to run RACADM RACRESETCFG at command prompt.
I've installed it on computer, and when I typed [server_ip_address]:1311 in the browser, nothing happens.
Server is connected to the computer. I can access "Dell Remote Access Controller 4/I" page, but cannot login.

Comment: What happens when you run the command at command prompt? Note one of the posts near the end said you do it from inside the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is a silly issue, but the resolve was uninstalling all dell related software and installing only omsa. After that was done, I was able to run that command.
By the way it only works on Windows Server 2003 for me.